# Co-cyclic group and abelian monolithic group

Tags: group-theory

A $\textbf{cocyclic group}$ is a group $G$ with  $\displaystyle\bigcap_{\{1\}\neq H\le G}H \neq\{1\}$.
By this referement: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cocyclic_group
result equivalent this conditiction:

1. $G$ is cocyclic.
2. $G$ has a non-trivial minimal subgroup $M$.
3. $G$ is isomorphic to a cyclic p-group $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ or Prüfer group $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ (for some prime number $p$).

It's obvious that $1)\Longrightarrow 2)$ and that $3)\Longrightarrow 1),2)$.
I ask why $2)\Longrightarrow 1)$ and if for $1)\Longrightarrow 3)$ is necessary the hypothesis that $G$ is abelian (in this case 1) is equivalent to saying that $G$ is monolithic and we have a description of abelian monolithic groups).

Ps. $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n}$ and $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ are the only groups with lattice of subgroups that is totally ordered.

Comment: (2) is not precisely worded. Any cyclic subgroup of prime order would be a "non-trivial minimal subgroup." What you need is a non-trivial *minimum* subgroup.